# How to add header via Swift mailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer, smtpclient

I am trying to add header to message sent via swift mailer.

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance($title)
          ->setFrom(array('mail@mail.com' => 'Name'))
          ->setTo(array($email => $email))
          ->setBody($content, 'text/html');
```

tried this, returns error

```
 $message-> addTextHeader('List-Unsubscribe', $url_unsub);
```

This returns does nothing, but does not return error also

```
$headers = $message->getHeaders();
$headers->addTextHeader('List-Unsubscribe', $url_unsub);      
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Any idea what to do?

Comment: [The documentation is really straight forward](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/headers.html). What does the error say? Can you check if the headers are actually added(see docs)?

Comment: I am using B2B cockpit of SAP.I have to remove headers from SWIFT message for my interface and java code or predefined process available to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, change to:

```
$message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('List-Unsubscribe', $url_unsub);
```

because you doesn't set/relate your `$headers` to `$message` after calling `getHeaders()`.

Second. Check if `$url_unsub` contains really proper format for header `"List-Unsubscribe"`. Look e.g. here => http://www.list-unsubscribe.com/

Comment: *"because you doesn't set/relate your $headers to $message after calling getHeaders()"* How is your one-liner different from the OP's last code block? Whether you assign the object returned by `getHeaders()` to a variable or not, does not change its identity, it's still linked to `$message` if it was in the first place.